# Divide an ArrayLists output

Tags: java, sqlite, arraylist

I am trying to come up with a dynamic solution for dividing these values which are going to be implemented into a `SQLite` database.

For example this output below should be divided before each `Px` (`x` is the value after `P`)

Output:

```
[P1, Nut, Red, 12, London, P2, Bolt, Green, 17, Paris, P3, Screw, Blue, 17, Rome, P4, Screw, Red, 14, London, P5, Cam, Blue, 12, Paris, P6, Cog, Red, 19, London]
```

What I would want is an output like

```
"INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES (P1, Nut, Red, 12, London)"
```

---

```
String query;
query = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES (";
for(int i=0; i< tableFields.size(); i++)
{ 
//For every value and column it creates a new line shown below so it becomes like        
// 'SNO' = 'S8' and so on.
query+= "'" + tableValues.get(i) + "',";
}
 //removes the last comma.
 query = query.substring(0, query.length()-1);
 query+= ")";
```

Comment: k, cool. What code did you write that didn't work after you asked this question so you can show us what you tried and what doesn't work? And how do you build that ArrayList? Because why would you not build and ArrayList of record objects that have an {id, string, string, int} structure, and give those an `.asSqlInsert()` method?

Comment: What I have done is reading a .txt filled with database info that I am supposed to convert into SQL statments and populate a database. And for all the code to make sense I think the only solution would show you the whole class. But That not might be appreciated? Since it is a quite big one

Comment: and where does that .txt file come from? This is real world or homework? because if it's real world, add delimiters to that txt data, or make it csv, then import with delimiter-aware code instead and done. Also, if the .txt contains database data, and it needs to GO into a database, I'd tell you to export as .sql, not as .txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your output is a `String`. I also assume that there will be exactly 4 values after every Px separated by a comma and a space.

Then you can split that `String` into an array using the `String.split(String)` method and iterate through the array and print the first five elements of the array, then the second five elements and so on.

This works:

```
String tableName = "aaa"; // just for the sake of testing it
String[] splittedOutput = yourOutputString.split(", ");
int valuesOnLine = 5; // EDIT
for (int i = 0; i < splittedOutput.length; i++) {
    if (i % valuesOnLine == 0) { // EDIT
        // 0 % 5 == 0, 5 % 5 == 0 etc., so we get here on every 5th element
        // which are the Px's, so we need to print the beginning of the line
        System.out.print("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES (");
    }
    System.out.print(splittedOutput[i]);
    if (i % valuesOnLine == valuesOnLine - 1) { // EDIT
        // we get here on the 4th, 9th, 14th, ... element, which means that
        // it's the last element that we'll print on that line
        System.out.println(")");
    } else {
        // if the condition above is not true, it's just some element
        // in the middle so we just print a comma and a space
        System.out.print(", ");
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
INSERT INTO aaa VALUES (P1, Nut, Red, 12, London)
INSERT INTO aaa VALUES (P2, Bolt, Green, 17, Paris)
INSERT INTO aaa VALUES (P3, Screw, Blue, 17, Rome)
INSERT INTO aaa VALUES (P4, Screw, Red, 14, London)
INSERT INTO aaa VALUES (P5, Cam, Blue, 12, Paris)
INSERT INTO aaa VALUES (P6, Cog, Red, 19, London)
```

If you want a different number of values on the line, modify the `valuesOnLine` variable.

Comment: Thanks this worked great! Nice work! Would be nice with a few comments in your code, it's nice with a walk-through when you are working with the modulus there!

Comment: I edited the answer and provided some explanation. Hopefully it's clear now. :) (Btw, I also simplified the code a bit.)

Comment: Oh, :( I just discovered a flaw! I have a table that only contains 3 rows and the output is no good.
`INSERT INTO [ J] ([J1, Sorter, Paris, J2, Punch);
INSERT INTO [ J] (Rome, J3, Reader, Athens, J4);
INSERT INTO [ J] (Console, Athens, J5, Collator, London);
INSERT INTO [ J] (J6, Termninal, Oslo, J7, Tape);
INSERT INTO [ J] (London], name:`

Comment: Well, look at what I assumed at the beginning of the answer. However, I already have an easy fix for that, I will update the answer in a minute.

Comment: Yea you are right, I am new to the site and I find everybodys code very attractive. I guess that I will learn in time :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one....

```
List<String> list =new ArrayList<String>();
```

Say list have the values

```
[P1, Nut, Red, 12, London, P2, Bolt, Green, 17, Paris, P3, Screw, Blue, 17, Rome, P4, Screw, Red, 14, London, P5, Cam, Blue, 12, Paris, P6, Cog, Red, 19, London]
```

Then the count from P1 to P2 will be 5

```
int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) 
{
  if(list.get(i).equals("P2"))
   count=i; // count will be 5
}

    Connection conn =null;
    PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("insert into table xx  values(?,?,?)");

    for(int j=0;j<list.size();) {
       for(int k=1;k<=count;k++,j++){
        st.setString(k, list.get(j)); 
        st.execute();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Is there maybe a way of making it more dynamic? Since this will only work if there isn't more than five values that are going to be inserted.

Comment: I think if you used his pseudocode right, it would work dynamically. You can also check my answer though. ;)

Comment: see my updated answer ....now it will work if there are more than five values  or less .....that are going to be inserted

Answer (score 0):

You may not require to check the if it starts with Px, 
Assuming

- Order of values always same
- No missing values in the sequence
- New  record to be inserted after every 4 values

  ```
       List<String> list =new ArrayList<String>();
      //list --> add values
      Connection conn =null;
      PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("insert into table xx  values(?,?,?,?)");

      for(int i=0;i<list.size();) {
          st.setString(1, list.get(i++)); 
          st.setString(2, list.get(i++)); //or setInt(..)
          st.setString(3, list.get(i++));
          st.setString(4, list.get(i++));
          st.execute();
      }
  ```

This again just to give an idea how process, connection part, setX, and execute method are to be modified accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...
 let arraylist be al..

int i=0;

while(i < al.size())
{

String sql= "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES (al.get(i), al.get(++i), al.get(++i), al.get(++i), al.get(++i))";

i++;

}